# Trigger on two or more tables with a dynamic query to execute inside those trigger - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

[image: flowchart]

I have a UI where the data comes from 4 tables M1,M2,M3,M4 and I got a save button which will Update data in these four tables.

Now I have a dynamic query in another table "tblDynamic". Which have some operations to do at different places of database or even it can Send Emails.

My requirement is whenever certain values in M1,M2,M3,M4 meets certain conditions. It should trigger this dynamic query.

**Ex:**

- In Table M1 I have a=1
- In Table M2 I have b=1
- In Table M3 I have c=2

**Dynamic Query:**

```
IF M1.a = M2.b OR M2.b <> M3.c
BEGIN
//execute some operation 
END
```

---

**Triggers on M1 M2 M3 M4**

```
Create trigger tgrM1 On M1    
BEGIN    
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)    
SELECT @Query = DynamicQuery FROM tblDynamic WHERE type = 'xyz'    
IF @Query <> ''    
BEGIN    
//fire some dynamic query    
END
```

My problem here is if I have trigger on both the tables 
So when there is an OR condition

I have to either fire M1 tables trigger or M2 tables trigger.
What if both the conditions are true?
I get the dynamic query fired twice

how to solve this? any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: why do you have both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] tagged?

Comment: It's a question for logic. so I thought any database developer can answer this. I need an answer no matter where it comes from :)

Comment: As I understood you don't want two trigger fires and in your IF statement you are using OR ... Can't you just split your IF into ELSE IF statement and that way you'll have just one trigger fire?

Comment: @Veljko89 What if both the conditions are true? and the triggers are firing from two tables. In first trigger IF part will execute and in the second trigger ELSE part will execute. And any how both the operations defined in dynamic query are the same. so if and else will have same query to execute. that don't make sense isn't?

Comment: But it won't ... it is bad design, yes ... but in IF ELSE statement it will only fire once, doesn't matter if both of conditions are true .. it will be something like this `IF (1 = 1) SELECT 1 ELSE IF (2 = 2) SELECT 2 ELSE SELECT 3`

Comment: @Veljko89 I agree about IF and IF ELSE. Here the problem is we have two triggers, and these IF statements are going to run on both these triggers and end up executing either of the condition. Which will execute the dynamic query in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by just adding a temp table to the database.
And moving the trigger onto that temp table.

While the save button is clicked for M1,M2,M3,M4 to save data from the UI.
The changed data is also inserted into "Mtemp" table from all four tables.

And the trigger on "Mtemp" table gets fired to perform my dynamic query operation. Using the combined data of M1, M2, M3, M4 into Mtemp.

Hope this will help someone who is facing similar issue.